# numpy array slicing, get one from each third dimension

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, indexing

I have a 3D array of data. I have a 2D array of indices, where the shape matches the first two dimensions of the data array, and it specfies the indices I want to pluck from the data array to make a 2D array. eg:

```
 from numpy import *
 a = arange(3 * 5 * 7).reshape((3,5,7))
 getters = array([0,1,2] * (5)).reshape(3,5)
```

What I'm looking for is a syntax like `a[:, :, getters]` which returns an array of shape (3,5) by indexing independently into the third dimension of each item. However, `a[:, :, getters]` returns an array of shape (3,5,3,5). I can do it by iterating and building a new array, but this is pretty slow:

```
 array([[col[getters[ri,ci]] for ci,col in enumerate(row)] for ri,row in enumerate(a)])
 # gives array([[  0,   8,  16,  21,  29],
 #    [ 37,  42,  50,  58,  63],
 #    [ 71,  79,  84,  92, 100]])
```

Is there a neat+fast way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I've done something like this using fancy indexing:

```
>>> k,j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(a.shape[1]),np.arange(a.shape[0]))
>>> k
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> j
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> a[j,k,getters]
array([[  0,   8,  16,  21,  29],
       [ 37,  42,  50,  58,  63],
       [ 71,  79,  84,  92, 100]])
```

Of course, you can keep `k` and `j` around and use them as often as you'd like.  As pointed out by DSM in comments below, `j,k = np.indices(a.shape[:2])` should also work instead of `meshgrid`.  Which one is faster (apparently) depends on the number of elements you are using.

Comment: Minor tweak: `j,k = np.indices(a.shape[:2])`.

Comment: indices is a very nice function, but to a short test it is 2 or 3 times less performant than meshgrid

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri: true enough, although `np.indices` wins for larger arrays; I get crossover at about 10^6 elements.

Comment: @DMS I guess it depends on the machine, for 10^6 elements ( shape (50,50,50) ) I obtain that np.indices takes twice the time. it's hard to say from the source code which one should perform better under which conditions...got any insight?

Comment: @DSM -- Thanks for that.  I had actually tried to solve this problem a while back and the solution I posted above was the best I could come up with.  As with many things `numpy`, it's neat to see that there are different ways of doing it.